# How to send Push notification in salesforce to custom objects

Tags: ios, push-notification, salesforce, apex

I have found a way in which push notification works if we use standard objects of salesforce but I want to send push notification to custom objects.

I have two apps and want to send push notification from one app's custom object to another app's custom object.

Please help if there is a way to acheive this.

Comment: As long as you are the developer of both applications, yes, this is possible. You'll need to handle the logic for transmitting the message from a user of app1 to the user of app2 in your backend.

Comment: but how can i manage? because in salesforce we define owner id in trigger and we have one owner i.e one salesforce account but we want to send push notification to custom users of different connected apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use third party service like firebase or pushwoosh for this. Standard push notification will not work of salesforce.